# Remove all backslashes from a string - php - regex

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

my string is

```
$str = '<img src="\"images/hai.jpg\"" alt="" /> Text <img src="\"images/hai.jpg\"" alt="" />';
```

i want to remove all  \"   from the string.

Comment: Use `stripslashes($str)`

Comment: How about a simple `str_replace`? `str_replace('\"', '', $str)` and you’re done.

Comment: This question is **not constructive**. No research from OP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you aren't looking for a regex, but for the [`stripslashes($str)`](http://php.net/stripslashes) method.

EDIT: From the comments, I understand that you will only replace `\"` with nothing, you should use a simple `str_replace` here, as @Gumbo said:

```php
$str = ...;
$newStr = str_replace('\"', '', $str);

echo $newStr;
```

You can use regular expressions for this, but the pReg library isn't fast, if you can find a str_* or array variant which does the same I always recommend to use that instead of preg_*

Comment: He wants to remove only `\"` and not all `\‍`.

Comment: @WouterJ : but i want to replace all \" . that $str is dynamic it may contain many \".

Comment: @FrancisMV123 I think that is exactly what my code does?

Answer (score 1):

Using `stripslashes($str)` will not always remove ALL `\`s from a string. If there is an instance where an `\\` exists, it will become one slash, not 0. To get rid of them all, the best thing maybe to be to use `str_replace`.

And also as stated by the OP, he wishes to remove `/"` which will need to be done using `str_replace`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the sort of data string that has been through more than one escape sequence.  You might want to look for the underlying cause of the backslashes and duplicated quotes.  In PHP, magic quotes can cause this sort of thing.  If you can get to this article it will explain the issues.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_6630-Magic-Quotes-a-bad-idea-from-day-one.html

HTH, ~Ray

Comment: This is on the verge of being a link-only answer.  Could you provide some additional context from the linked article?  Also, while it's totally true that double-escaping and/or magic quotes can cause the general problem, judging from the OP's actual problem, that doesn't seem to be the case here.