# Remove backslashes before slashes in php

Tags: php

I am using this php code to remove backslashes in my array:

```
$data[] = $_POST;

function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}

$data = stripslashes_deep($data);
```

but I still have a backslash before the slashes like this:

```
"2''1\/2"
```

Can you please help remove this backslash in php.

Thanks

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904014/remove-all-backslashes-from-a-string-php-regex)

Answer (score 0):

This will work, to remove \

```
$value= preg_replace('@\\\\@','',$value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function stripslashes_deep($item){
    return stripslashes($item);
}

if(is_array($data)){
    $value=array_map('stripslashes_deep', $data);
}
else{
    $value=stripslashes($data);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300846/4231110

Answer (score 0):

I found it's much simpler using a foreach

`foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
    $data[$key] = stripslashes($value);
}`

instead of the conditional operator and the recursive call..